# Does Power DVD have any command line options to automatically play a DVD in fullscreen?

Tags: command-line, htpc, powerdvd

I'd like to launch PowerDVD8 from a shortcut and have it automatically start the DVD/BluRay and display in fulllscreen mode. Is this possible?

Comment: PowerDVD does not have command line parameters like that, but Zoom Player does: http://www.inmatrix.com/zplayer/parameters.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-Click your PowerDVD Shortcut,
   choose Properties
2. In the Shortcut tab, go to Target
3. Go to the end of the text for the
   Target and add **/fullscreen_mode_on** 
   (put this outside of the quotes if
   there are any)